# How to resolve graphene DjangoFilterConnectionField?

Tags: django, graphene-python

I have below queries in my graphene API list,

```
class Query(UserQuery, graphene.ObjectType):
    all_users = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        UserType, filterset_class=UserFilter)
    all_leagues = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        LeagueType, filterset_class=LeagueFilter)
```

For these connections fields I need to apply @login_required style permission.

I found that I need to resolve these api endpoints in order to apply those.

```
@login_required
def resolve_all_users(self, info):
    #code
```

But I don't know what to return from the above method?
There is a model called Users and ideally all records from that model needs to be returned.

But when I apply filter on first, last, before, after, I get below error,

```
"message": "Query.resolve_all_users() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first'"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Below code shows how to resolve the DjangoFilterConnectionField and it is similar to any other Django query resolve method.

```
    @login_required
    def resolve_all_users(self, info, **kwargs):
        user = info.context.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            return User.objects.all()
        else:
            return User.objects.filter(user_id=user.user_id)
```